# Check if a file is corrupted using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that selects multiple PDF files in a user specified folder, parses through them, grabs specified data, and backfills it into a spreadsheet.

I have error handling for instances such as if the file is locked, but not for if the file is corrupt.

Within testing, the code actually manages to some how open the corrupted document and pull garbage, but I would like to just have a simple if statement that detects whether the file is corrupted or not.

Does anybody know if it is possible to check a non-excel file to see if it is corrupted using VBA?

Comment: When you say it "pulls garbage", what is it pulling? Maybe you could check the status of whatever you're trying to grab?

Comment: Without any information about what a sane file looks like? Define "corrupted".

Comment: The word "corrupted" is too broad, and as such is unanswerable. Obviously you have some expectation of some certain data structure within the PDF, but you don't share how you are parsing the structure, in which case it might not be "corruption" but rather reading in random data that weren't in the format you expected it to be. Post the code and provide example input/output.

Comment: @dwirony - It just manages to pull random characters that I don't even recognize. Screenshot here [link](https://i.imgur.com/SlkdN7u.png)
I actually do have code in there that checks for non-numeric values and flags the results if it fails (hence the red text)

To answer the rest, to create a test 'Corrupted file' I took one of these PDFs, opened it using regular notepad, and deleted a large chunk of text. When attempting to open this file normally, acrobat reader greets me with "This file is damaged and could not be repaired." 
It is this that I would like to try and test for in VBA.